# New project: ADO.Net vs Entity Framework - trying to understand if EF works out

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

we are at the beginning of a new project, which will replace a legacy project. The legacy one is written in .Net Framework 4.0 (SOA with WCF) + SQL Server. The connection with SQL is made by ADO.Net + stored procedures. There is a structural mistake by having most of the logic on the stored procedures, and on top of that, it is a monolytic.

The new project will be made with .Net 6 APIs and in some cases, it will have SQL Server as well, for operational data.

So, looking at the new product the question was raised: should we move from ADO.Net to EF? This is tempting since it reduces the development effort, but performance is a concern.

Taking a look at the technical must haves:

- Get the product to be as fast as possible (performance is a concern)
- The new project is expected to live at least for the next 15 years
- Operations are executed against tables with 30 to 50 million records
- We must be able to run operations against the regular database, but also against the readonly one (AlwaysOn)
- We must be able to perform some resiliency policies such as retries in case of deadlocks
- We don't have much room for changes if we choose one path and somewhere along the way we realize we should had gone with the other option

Quite honestly, IMHO, based on our tech requirements I feel should move forward with ADO.Net + Stored procedures (without any business logic) + some sort of package that translates the SQL results to my objects in a fast manner, but I'd like to give EF a shot, at least on this stage of the process where we are investigating possibilities.

I'd like to gather if possible opinions, specially if there is someone out there that went to EF with requirements as similar as ours, or someone who didn't go to EF or had to change from EF to ADO.Net somewhere along the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed as it is both opinion based and too broad. I will state the obvious that ORM benefits are not a free lunch and you need attention to detail over the full stack of components to get maximum performance. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/).

Comment: EF uses ADO.NET internally, so trying to compare the two directly is a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in your requirements that could support using ADO.NET over EF is

> Get the product to be as fast as possible (performance is a concern)

Which is a nonsense requirement, as you can always write more code and make things more complex to make things marginally faster.  You need a *real* performance requirement so you can measure different approaches.